# How to remove vertical lines from img

Tags: image, opencv, lines, feature-detection

I have a problem to find digits in pictures attached bellow. It is caused by vertical lines which sometimes occur and sometimes it's not. I'm looking for idea how to remove these vertical lines them from pictures.

I've tried contour detection, but it selected line and closest digit when it occur to close. I've also tried morphological transformation but it removes to much pixels from digits.

To remove short lines I've tried looking on the upper half of image and from it detect where occur gap. After found gaps I've stretched it vertically but again it remove to much. Hough transform also isn't helpful.

Images:

[image: img 1]

[image: img 2]

[image: img 3]

[image: img 4]

[image: img 5]

[image: img 6]

[image: img 7]

[image: img 8]

Comment: Just a hint: if you try to remove the vertical lines, how can you be sure to do not remove a 1 by mistake?

Comment: that's the point, i want to remove vertical lines only between digits. Vertical lines in 1 have to be left untouched

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the function in [OpenCV](https://opencv.org) `cvMatchTemplate()` since the numbers are consistent. Other approach would be using the libraries for [Support Vector Machines](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html)

This can be also done in [SimpleCV](http://simplecv.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can divide pictures by digits' width, you use [erosion](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/erode.htm) and then dylatation, as it is definitely the easiest way. It should work properly on pictures: 1,2,3,8. You may experiment with using those two operation in many proportions, like 2 erosions, 2 dylatations; 2 erosion, 1 dylatation etc.

Generally filters meant for eliminating lines are logical filters (verticaly positioned) and mediane filters. You can also support mediane filter by previous dylatation, because usually lines you want to erase are thinner than your digits. After performing mediane you can use erosion again.

Another possibility is to use vertical sobel filter (put effect in buffer), then erode/logical/mediane original picture, and finaly merge both. Sobel will emphasize horizontal edges, so after merging it will undo erosion effect but only on numbers. Propably it will leave tiny spots in places around lines top end, but it's easily erasable by any low-pass filter.

Ps. whenever eroding, convoluting or filtering, do it only in vertically aligned pixels to take greatest advantage of thiner lines.